# click to load Google plus javascript to show comments

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, google-plus, blogger

Hi i want to load comments from google plus. what people are posted on google plus from my website.
i actually just installed this code in WordPress blog post. if a user wants to reply to post by clicking on Google+ button to load code from Google plus and load comments.

```
<button onClick="showGoogle();">Google+</button>

<div style="max-width:100%" id="loading">
<div id="gpcomments" style="max-width:100%"></div>
</div>

<script>
gapi.comments.render('gpcomments', {
    href:'http://findsgood.com/?p=43224',
    width: '682',
    first_party_property:'BLOGGER',
    view_type: 'FILTERED_POSTMOD','callback' : function showGoogle() {src='https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';}});
</script>
```

Comment: So what is your problem? What is happening and what do you want to happen?

Comment: hey i replied answer  here but still i have a another problem can you solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plusone.js` is being loaded asynchronously but `gapi` is being called synchronously. `gapi` isn't available until `plusone.js` is finished loading. You can use an `onload` event to wait until `gapi` is ready for use.

```
<button onClick="showGoogle();">Google+</button>

<div style="max-width:100%" id="loading"><div id="gpcomments" style="max-width:100%"></div></div>

<script>
function showGoogle() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    script.onload = function() {
        gapi.comments.render('gpcomments', {
            href:'http://findsgood.com/?p=43224',
            width: '682',
            first_party_property:'BLOGGER',
            view_type: 'FILTERED_POSTMOD'
        });
    }
    head.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Comment: wow. excellent dude. thank you so much abraham. its working. you are the one my first inspiration of learning javascript.

Answer (score 1):

finally found code working but i have to click button twice. i don't know why i need to click two times?. please someone help?

```
<button onClick="showGoogle();">Google+</button>

<div style="max-width:100%" id="loading"><div id="gpcomments" style="max-width:100%"></div></div>

<script>function showGoogle() {
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      head.appendChild(script);
gapi.comments.render('gpcomments', {
    href:'http://findsgood.com/?p=43224',
    width: '682',
    first_party_property:'BLOGGER',
    view_type: 'FILTERED_POSTMOD'
});}
</script>
```

you can run test here a on blog post http://findsgood.com/?p=43224

Answer (score 0):

First click generates an error in the console, for the sake of testing try to include `plusone.js` in theme header manually. (this feels more like a comment, just can't add them yet).

Comment: Actually i don't want load and include unnecessary scripts in header. that's why implemented this code. the only problem is have to click twice. still i am looking to solve problem.

Comment: That's the thing, it looks like Google API is being loaded after first click, by adding it to header you could rule out if that's the reason.

Comment: oh god! if i added to header or bottom of html then i will face page speed. take a look page speed of this page goo.gl/okdME8